# Getting an error in my C++ CaesarCipher Program

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am trying to create a caesar cipher in c++ but I keep getting this error when trying to build the program, any help?
The Error I'm receiving is as follows:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid Aborted (core
>   dumped)

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string caesarCipher(string text, int ciphe);

int main(void)  {
string text, encodedString; 
int ciphe = 0;
cout << "Please enter a word: ";
getline(cin, text);
cout << "Key: ";
cin >> ciphe;

encodedString = caesarCipher(text, ciphe);
cout <<"Encrypted: " << encodedString << "\n";

return 0;
}

string caesarCipher(string text, int ciphe)
{
string temp = text;
int length;

length = (int)temp.length();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
      if(isalpha(temp[i]))
      {
        for (int x = 0; x < ciphe; x++)
        {
          if (temp[i] == 'z')
          {
              temp[i] = 'a';
          }
          else
          {
            temp[i]++;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program _builds_ (or _compiles_) correctly, but it doesn't _run_ correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I didn't face any compilation error with this code except that there is a small bug in the `caesarCipher` routine.

You have to actually return the `temp` string instead of `0` to get a correct answer.

The correct code should be

```
string caesarCipher(string text, int ciphe)
{
string temp = text;
int length;

length = (int)temp.length();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
      if(isalpha(temp[i]))
      {
        for (int x = 0; x < ciphe; x++)
        {
          if (temp[i] == 'z')
          {
              temp[i] = 'a';
          }
          else
          {
            temp[i]++;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't face any compilation error with your code. it is compiling successfully on my machine and i also crosschecked with ideone. it is compiling correctly.

add `return temp;` statement at the end of the function instead of `return 0;`

check here- http://cpp.sh/5eo2r